# Android OpenCV color segmentation display on ImageView

Tags: android, c++, opencv, colors

I have searched everywhere for a solution but I haven't found any. I know this is a recurrent question, so I'll try to be precise.

I want to perform color segmentation in HSV using Android and OpenCV. I have an array of HSV samples corresponding to the color I want to segment, from which I obtain `mean` and `std` in order to obtain a range of values like:

```
lowerBoundH = new Scalar(meanSamples[0]-stdSamples[0]);
lowerBoundS = new Scalar(meanSamples[1]-stdSamples[1]);
upperBoundH = new Scalar(meanSamples[0]+stdSamples[0]);
upperBoundS = new Scalar(meanSamples[1]+stdSamples[1]);
```

Once I obtain these ranges for H, S and V I do the following (I only work with channels H & S):

```
mH = new Mat();
mS = new Mat();
List<Mat> channels = new ArrayList<Mat>(2);

// convert inputFrame to HSV for segmentation
Mat hsvFrame = new Mat();
convertToHSV(inputFrame, hsvFrame);
Core.split(hsvFrame, channels);
// get H&S channels of the HSVimage
mH = channels.get(0);
mS = channels.get(1);

if(mH!=null & mS!=null){
    mHinRange = new Mat();
    mSinRange = new Mat();
    Core.inRange(mH, lowerBoundH, upperBoundH, mHinRange);
    Core.inRange(mS, lowerBoundS, upperBoundS, mSinRange);
    Mat filtered = new Mat(hsvFrame.height(), hsvFrame.width(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(4));

    Core.bitwise_and(mHinRange, mSinRange, filtered);
    Mat aux = new Mat();
    Mat mRgb = new Mat();
    inputFrame.copyTo(mRgb);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(filtered, mRgb, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR, 0);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgb, aux, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA, 0);

    return aux;
}else{
    Log.v("NULL","H OR S CHANNELS ARE NULL");
    return null;
}
```

Then, I convert that segmented `Mat` to `Bitmap` in order to display it in an `ImageView` like so:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
Mat tmp = new Mat(result.height(),result.width(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(4));
try {
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(tmp.cols(), tmp.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp);
}catch (CvException e){Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());}
qrImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

But when I display the resulting image I get a completely black image. I know this is wrong because the camera is facing directly to the colored object I want to segment.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a stupid mistake. I was creating the Bitmap from the empty `tmp` Mat.

Instead, I need to create it using the `result` Mat:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
try {
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(result.cols(), result.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(result, bmp);
}catch (CvException e){Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());}
qrImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```